# Use my custom initialier to initialize my table cell (inherit UITableViewCell)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitableview

I have created my custom table cell class:

```
@interface CommonCell : UITableViewCell{
   ...
}

@end
```

In the implementation file of it, I have created a **custom initializer** method:  `initWithCellHeight:reuseIdentifier:showName`

which called the `[super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])` , like below:

```
@implementation CommonCell

- (id)initWithCellHeight:(float)cellHeight reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier showName:(BOOL)showName
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {

        [self createViews: showName];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I use my cell class in my controller in the following way:

```
#import "CommonCell.h"

...
cell = [[[CommonCell alloc] initWithCellHeight:150 reuseIdentifier:@"CommonCellId" showName:YES] autorelease];
```

I got **warning** message : `instance method "initWithCellHeight:reuseIdentifier:showName" not found`

Why? Why I can not use my custom initialiser for my table cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is `- (id)initWithCellHeight:(float)cellHeight reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier showName:(BOOL)showName` not present in the header file? You will need to declare it before using it to remove the warning.

Comment: You are right! I forget to declare it in my header file. I have to wait for 5min to accept your answer , thank you!:)